# Background image in HTML table does not show in most browsers

Tags: html, google-sites

The page at www.patbanks.com is supposed to have a pretty image for the background.  It shows on Safari, but not on Chrome or Firefox.  (Didn't try IE.)

This is a Google Sites so I am not allowed to use CSS; please forgive the awful table-based code.  Also unable to put the background in the BODY tag. So the image is in a TABLE tag. This is the only known way to get a background image.

(Answers that I researched were either about subtly different situations where CSS can be used properly, or about malformed URLs.  I already verified that the image itself is accessible from that bizarre upload URL.)  I am probably doing something offensive to the TABLE tag, or the Google-injected wrapper is doing something to thwart me.  Except, the page works just fine when viewed by of all things, Safari...)

Comment: Surely you can use CSS at Google Sites; even the page mentioned uses CSS.

Comment: You can't apply a background image like that. You've tried to set an attribute (background) of the table element. Only problem is, it doesn't have one with this name. You _can_ use an attribute called `bgcolor`, but `background` doesn't exist. (http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_table.asp) Then only thing I can think of is to use the style attribute (inline css) I.e `style="background-image: url(https://9fccad2f-a-40d70200-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/patbanks.com/bizcard2/seashore.jpg)"`

Comment: I do see a background image on Chrome (though I would not call it pretty). But whatever you are doing would most probably be best done otherwise.

Comment: Hopefully someone with experience in Google Sites will know an answer.  This question depends on that.  This is not a normal HTML situation.

Comment: I think there might be some kind of XSS issue here.  The image is not in the same domain as the page.  Accessing through the secret "real" URL, not the mapped one, I think it always works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the location of the image.

The real URL for the site is https://sites.google.com/a/{user/internal site name}/home.   The published ("mapped") URL is just http://www.patbanks.com.

Originally, I uploaded it in the Attachments menu, and used the corresponding image URL.  That points to some upload server (the terminal subdomain in the URL is like my Google Sites site name).  That URL does not work for some browsers; it is ignored. I don't quite understand why, but it is definitely the case that it is referencing something "off site".  Perhaps it is an XSS-prevention feature in the browser (since it worked anyway in some browsers, and not others).

The solution was to edit the page and use the Upload Image command.  This creates the image with a very different URL than the Attachments does. (Then I used the HTML editor to remove the resulting unwanted IMG tag, and copied the URL to the TABLE background attribute.)

The page now displays with the background, in all browsers.

Google Sites used to have an "Entire Page Background" command, which I imagine used a CSS style in a DIV or on the BODY element.  That's how I wrote the page before I tried to port it to Google Sites, but Google removed this functionality.  There is still lots of documentation and third-party help pages that refer to that feature.  That no workie no more.  And Google Sites doesn't support CSS generally, because it interferes with their CMS.  It automatically rewrites/redacts whatever HTML you input on your page.

Someday I'll understand exactly what was going wrong, but hopefully the workaround I've described here will be useful for people.